# startActivityForResult implementation in an Android Service

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I have written a service which triggers some application's activity ( not my app's ) say the default web browser. How do i determine from the service if this web browser activity is finished? I understand that startActivityForResult is not possible from a service.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks
Mahadevan